# Sudo command not working on Intel Galileo Gen 1

Tags: ssh, terminal, intel

I have an Intel Galileo Gen 1 Arduino board and I am using it over SSH with Ethernet. When I try to use the sudo commands the bash terminal reports this, a missing command! I am using the bigger Linux image for the Galileo aka Yokto Linux. Here is a screen shot...
[image]

Is there a solution to this?
Thanks & Regards
Isaac Cilia Attard

Answer (score 0):

The trivial solution seems to be: Install `sudo`...

For that you need a way to become `root` first, of course.

1. Try to log in as `root` with SSH.
2. Try `su -` from your SSH user login.

Comment: What do you mean by "Install sudo"?

Comment: @IsaacCiliaAttard You are not familiar with the concept of installing software after an OS has been installed? Is that what you want to tell me? Or is your Arduino Linux the only distro which does not offer additional packages?

Comment: I know how to use the Debian package manager and RedHat based package managers but Yokto uses OPKG which is not pre-configured on the Galileo so its a bit dificult to install packages for Yokto. So then, how do I install Sudo, on Yokto of course?